# Sum of non-blank cells with sign inversion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

suppose I have a set of rows with numbers. Some columns in these rows are blank. Each row however contains an even number of non-blank cells as follows:

```
row_1: 3 4 # 7 # 3
row_2: 5 # 3 7 # 8
row_3: # # 5 # # 3
...
```

where `#` is an empty cell.

I would like to find a formula that will compute the following (using row_1 as an example):

```
= -3 + 4 + -7 + 3
```

In other words, the formula is to compute the sum of non-blank cells where the value of every odd non-blank cell has an inverted sign.

**Question:** Is it possible to do it without VBA just with some excel formula? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are there only 6 columns????

Comment: The number of columns is fixed and all the rows have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on data in `A1:F1`, **array formula****

`=SUM(INDEX(1:1,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(A1:F1<>{"";""},COLUMN(A1:F1))))))*-1^ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A1:F1))))`

Copy down to give similar results for data in `A2:F2`, `A3:F3`, etc.

As way of an explanation, using the data provided, this part:

`N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(A1:F1<>{"";""},COLUMN(A1:F1)))))`

produces an array of column indices for which the entry within row 1 of that column is non-blank, i.e.:

`{1;2;4;6}`

We then pass these to `INDEX`, such that:

`INDEX(1:1,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(A1:F1<>{"";""},COLUMN(A1:F1))))))`

which is:

`INDEX(1:1,{1;2;4;6})`

gives:

`{3;4;7;3}`

which is then multiplied by the result of:

`-1^ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A1:F1)))`

which is:

`-1^ROW(A1:A4)`

i.e.:

`-1^{1;2;3;4}`

i.e.:

`{-1;1;-1;1}`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain how this formula works?

Comment: Sure. Have added to the post.

Comment: Or maybe just : `=NPV(-2,A1:F1)*1` ;)

Comment: You and your NPV! :-)

Answer (score 1):

How does this work? You'll need to use helper columns. (There may be a way to skip that and combine the helper formula with `Sum()`, but I'm not there yet :P )

[image]

The formula to put in H1, and drag right/down is:
`=IF(A1<>"",IF(MOD(COUNTA($A1:A1),2)=1,-1*A1,A1),"")`

Then just sum up those numbers (column O above) to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In column G, use the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1)
```

Then in column H use this formula:

```
=-MID(G1,1,1)+MID(G1,2,1)+IF(LEN(G1)>2,-MID(G1,3,1)+MID(G1,4,1),0)
```

This is assuming you only have six columns, at least two of them are always filled in, and at least two will be blank. If you fall outside of that criteria, you will have to additionally modify it.